# Frame id for cansend

Tags: ruby, can-bus

The definition of cansend method in ruby is this:

```
cansend can0 123#1122334455667788
```

will send a message on interface can0 with identifier 0x123

So if I have a CAN frame like this:

```
<0x0000eb00> [8] 04 76 02 15 ff ff ff ff
```

What is the frame id in cansend for the CAN frame above?
For me the above Frame Id is "eb00" but cansend only allows 3 bytes frame ID. 
For example what will the cansend frame id be for example "ec22"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For CAN 2.0 you can send either standard frames, i.e. CAN ID will have 3 hex chars or extended frames, i.e. CAN ID will have 8 hex chars.

```
cansend can0 123#0011
```

or

```
cansend can0 0000eb00#0011
```

This is true for `cansend` command line tool.